# Дефолтный ключ NSUserDefaults

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Доброго времени суток. У меня такая проблема: в приложении есть, условно говоря, две кнопки, каждая из которых задает значение ключу для NSUserDefaults. Нужно, чтобы уже при первом запуске приложения ключ имел какое-то дефолтное значение, а кнопки только меняли его. Как это реализовать? Недавно делал, а теперь забыл как. Надеюсь на помощь, спасибо.

Comment: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool needInit = ![pref boolForKey:SETTINGS_ALREADYRUN];
if (needInit) { 
    // инициируем настройки
    [pref setBool:true forKey:SETTINGS_ALREADYRUN];
    [pref synchronize];
}
```

Оно?

Comment: Нашел другое решение, но все равно спасибо за отзывчивость!

Comment: А какое другое если не секрет, Settings bundle? Если да, то имейте в виду, что такие настройки можно править из меню настроек операционной системы и, что более важно, при каждом выходе приложения из спящего режима нужно дергать synchronize иначе настройки внутри приложения не обновятся

Comment: Нет, я сделал так:
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        
        NSString *result = [defaults objectForKey:@"MyKey"];
        
        if (!result)
        {

        }

А вот с Settings Bundle проблема возникла: я добавил его в проект, но потом понял, что это не то, что мне нужно, и удалил Settings Bundle, но при запуске приложения на симуляторе меню из настроек не попало никуда, как его убрать?

Comment: очистите проект в среде и сбросьте настройки симулятора, это известная проблема с ресурсами - они остаются в уже собранном бандле после удаления из проекта.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо!